# IPFS issue: can't upload files with ipfs.add(file)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ipfs

guys.
Few month ago I add ipfs for upload files, all worked correctly, but a week ago I have problem and can’t resolve it.
I try to send file to IPFS and get hash of file.

like this.
connect ipfs :

```
  ipfs = await Ipfs.create({
      config: {
        Bootstrap: [
          '/dns4/ams-1.bootstrap.libp2p.io/tcp/443/wss/ipfs/QmSoLer265NRgSp2LA3dPaeykiS1J6DifTC88f5uVQKNAd',
          '/dns4/lon-1.bootstrap.libp2p.io/tcp/443/wss/ipfs/QmSoLMeWqB7YGVLJN3pNLQpmmEk35v6wYtsMGLzSr5QBU3',
          '/dns4/sfo-3.bootstrap.libp2p.io/tcp/443/wss/ipfs/QmSoLPppuBtQSGwKDZT2M73ULpjvfd3aZ6ha4oFGL1KrGM',
          '/dns4/node0.preload.ipfs.io/tcp/443/wss/ipfs/QmZMxNdpMkewiVZLMRxaNxUeZpDUb34pWjZ1kZvsd16Zic',
          '/dns4/node1.preload.ipfs.io/tcp/443/wss/ipfs/Qmbut9Ywz9YEDrz8ySBSgWyJk41Uvm2QJPhwDJzJyGFsD6'
        ]
      }
    });

    console.timeEnd('IPFS Started');
```

and try to send file

```
  const {ipfs, ipfsInitError} = useIpfs({commands: ['id']});
  const addToIpfs = async (file) => {
    const hashOfFile = await ipfs.add(file);

    return hashOfFile[0].path;
};
```

so, when I try to upload, I have error

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): undefined is not an object (evaluating ‘hashOfFile[0].path’)
in hashOfFile return function
AsyncGenerator {_invoke: function, next: function, throw: function, return: function, Symbol(Symbol.asyncIterator): function}
``
earlier it was hash of file.

could you help me?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on GitHub I have answer from developers

> Previously ipfs.add returned an array, which was great, unless you
>   were adding a lot of files in which case your process could run out of
>   memory. Now it returns an async iterator as you've found. n.b. you
>   don’t need to do the double await:

```
// instead of
for await (const inputFile of await ipfs.add({ path: 'randompath.txt', content: file })) {

// do:
for await (const inputFile of ipfs.add({ path: 'randompath.txt', content: file }))
```

it work, but still problem in Safari - crash

```
    Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): null is not an object (evaluating 'ipfs.add')
```

[image]